# How to not overwriting my sqlite database in AdoniJS?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite, adonis.js

I made an API that loads data from another API, store data in a sqlite database. I have 4 parameters in my route and after that my application check if that input is in my database, if it is the value is returned from database and if it isn't the value is returned from the main API. The problem is sometimes, i don't know when, my database is overwriting the last input.

async index({
    request,
    response
  }) {

```
const date = request.input('date');
const hourInput = request.input('hour');
const lat = request.input('lat');
const lon = request.input('lon');

const weatherData = await Weather
  .query()
  .where('lat', '=', lat)
  .where('long', '=', lon)
  .where('hour', '=', hourInput)
  .where('date', '=', date)
  .fetch()
if (weatherData.rows[0]) {
  console.log("exista")
  response.json(weatherData.rows[0].temp_c)
} else {
  try {
    const history = await axios.get('http://api.apixu.com/v1/history.json?key=' + WEATHER_KEY + '&q=' + lat + ',' + lon + '&dt=' + date)
    for (let i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
      const hour = history.data.forecast.forecastday[0].hour[i].time.slice(11, 13);
      if (hourInput === hour) {
        const temp = history.data.forecast.forecastday[0].hour[i].temp_c;
        weather.lat = lat;
        weather.long = lon;
        weather.date = date;
        weather.hour = hourInput;
        weather.temp_c = temp;
        await weather.save();
        response.json(temp)
        console.log("Nu")
      }

      //response.json(weatherData.rows);
    }


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    //response.status(500).json({})
  }
}
```

}

Can someone explain me why my database is overwriting?